# Getting Last 2 month employee count at column level using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the last 2 months employee count at column level.

```
Below is my data:
yearmm, emp_cnt
201908,100
201907,200
201906,300
201904,600
```

Expected output: in the above example since there is no data for 201905, the yearmonth-2 for the 3rd row is 0.

```
Yearmonth, emp_cnt, Yearmonth-1_Cnt,Yearmonth-2_Cnt
201908,100,200,300
201907,200,300,600
201906,300,600,0
201904,600,0,0
```

My effort: I used lag to get the last two month based on order by first col  but if there is any missing data for a month it takes the previous one. Can anyone help me overcome this challenge.

```
with test_exp(yyyymonth,cnt) as(
    select 201908,100 union
        select 201907,200 union
        select 201906,300 union
        select 201904,600 )
    select yyyymonth,cnt,LAG(cnt, 1) OVER(
            ORDER BY
                yyyymonth
        ) AS "M-yyyymonth-1_Cnt"
        ,LAG(cnt, 2) OVER(
            ORDER BY
                yyyymonth
        ) AS "M-yyyymonth-2_Cnt" from test_exp
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: You can use windowing clause, like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e7b094b6fc780cfc7afc366cac489aeb).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method to use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(yearmonth) over (order by yearmonth) = yearmonth - 1
             then lag(empcnt) over (order by yearmonth)
             else 0
        end) as yearmonth_1,
       (case when lag(yearmonth, 2) over (order by yearmonth) = yearmonth - 1
             then lag(empcnt, 2) over (order by yearmonth)
             else 0
        end) as yearmonth_2
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that the dates are all within a single year.  You have not clearly specified the database (nor the type of `yearmonth`, so I'm just using subtraction to indicate checking if a value is one month back.

Comment: its in Oracle. so for 201901, will it get the count for dec and nov last year?

Comment: @PAS . . . No, the answer is quite clear that it doesn't work across year boundaries.